# Restore colors from an infrared frame in Gimp

Tags: gimp, infrared, infrared-conversion

I have some frames of a security IR camera. The images are black and white.
Is there any way to represent these images with colors.
I use GIMP in Ubuntu operating system.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no colours to restore; the image was recorded in black and white. You could create a false colour image by switching the image to a paletted image (256 colours), then assigning a different colour palette. I'm not familiar enough with the GIMP (and, people, the "the" is not optional; the name of the program is "the GIMP") to know whether it has a split-toning option in the current(ish) releases or add-ins, but you can use that to false-colour a black-and-white image as well. If you're interested in recovering the original colours in the scene, though, you're out of luck—you'd need to hand-tint the image.

Comment: So, on [gimp.org](http://www.gimp.org/), it says "_GIMP is the GNU Image Manipulation Program._" — no _the_.

Comment: One of the programmers at work once asked me if i knew how to make a Mask in GIMP..... much LOLz were had once he realised what hed asked for :-)

Comment: "**the** GNU Image Manipulation Program"...

Comment: Yes, but not (necessarily) "the GIMP".

Comment: Can you migrate a comments thread to "English" ??!!

Answer (score 2):

Nope - sorry!

All colour information is lost (unrecorded), it cannot be recovered, no matter what software you use.